# .gls file not created, therefore no glossary printed

Tags: miktex, glossaries, texstudio

i am currently working on my bachelorthesis. For acronyms I am using the package acronym. For my glossaries i would like to use the glossaries package.

As working environment I use miktex and Texstudio. For some reason i don't get a working glossary. As an Error i get the following messages:

[image: Erorr Message]
So its pretty clear, that something with the \makeglossaries seems to not work. But i cannot imageine what. I alreadey checked, that the makeglossaries.exe is correctly linked to texstudio and yes it is:

[image: Texstudio configuration]

So I really have no idea anyomore and I would be glad if somebody has a hint for me, why this is not working...

(And its not my bitdefender ransomware security tool. I prooved that it won't block makeglossaries.exe and didn't

Here is a minimal working code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{computer}
{
    name=computer,
    plural=computers,
    description={is a programmable machine that receives input,
        stores and manipulates data, and provides
        output in a useful format}
}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{TEST}\label{ch:Test}
        In our company we are using \glspl{computer}.
    \begin{appendix}
        \printglossaries
    \end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: Welcome, are you clicking some button to actually run the `makeglossaries` program?

Comment: No i didn't run sth. like that. Shouldn't it be run automatically while compiling? Sorry, I am a newby to LaTeX :)

Comment: Okay... in the Tools menu there is a "Glossary" button. I pressed it and got this error: Prozess gestartet: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/makeglossaries.exe" "glossary"

makeglossaries.exe: The script engine could not be found. makeglossaries.exe: Data: scriptEngine="perl.exe"
Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)

Comment: You need a working installation of Perl to work.

Comment: No, you are in charge of compiling. If you want some program to decide for you, have a look at `latexmk`. It might even run the correct program without a working perl installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a working Perl environment (e.g. Strawberry Perl) solved my Problem.

Thanks you for your help guys.

[image: Working Glossary]

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises because the 'makeglossaries' command (that generates the .gls file) is not called before pdflatex is invoked.

Step 1. Make sure that 'Makeglossaries' command is properly defined as "makeglossaries.exe" under "Commands" option in TexStudio.

Step 2. Enable 'Show Advanced Options' and configure your 'Build' settings in TexStudio to compile pdflatex, make glossary, and compile pdflatex again.

To do this, replace your "Build & View" option (that we may typically invoke using keyboard shortcut 'F5') as follows:

Before:

```
txs:///compile | txs:///view
```

After:

```
txs:///compile | txs:///makeglossaries | txs:///compile | txs:///view
```

Comment: Instead of changing the `Build & View` command, the `Default Compiler` command (defines what `tsx:///compile` does) can be changed as `txs:///pdflatex | txs:///makeglossaries | txs:///pdflatex`. I believe it is a more suitable place to make this change.

Comment: @TurgutSarıçam Doing that would make it harder to change the compiler without changing the whole chain.